# How to override S#arp architecture automapping with HBM files?

Tags: .net, composite, fluent, automapping, hbm

I'm facing problems with composite keys in S#arp architecture. Anyone have an example of how to do that or how to use mapping files with automapping?

Answer (score 0):

have you check the FluentNhibernate Wiki?

http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping

there is some great meterial there

also

http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2009/01/16/using-fluentnhibernate-to-map-composite-keys-for-a-table.aspx

this may help

Hope this helps